# Prove f(x) = max_i x_i is convex

Tags: solution-verification, convex-analysis

I want to prove $f(x) = \max_i x_i$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n$ is finite. Can you verify if my attempt at a proof is correct? Thanks in advance!

My attempt:

First off, we prove that $$f(ax) = a f(x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n, a \geq 0$$

Suppose this weren't true, because $\max_i a x_i > a \max_i x_i$. Then there exists an $i$ such that $a x_i > a \max_i x_i$. But by definition, $x_i \leq \max_i x_i$ and we can just multiply both sides by $a \geq 0$ to get $a x_i \leq a \max_i x_i$, and of course $x_i \leq a x_i \leq a \max_i x_i$, a contradiction.

Conversely, suppose this weren't true because $\max_i a x_i < a \max_i x_i$. Then:

1. there exists an $i$ such that $x_i > x_j \forall j \neq i$
2. there exists a $j$ such that $a x_j > a x_k \forall k \neq j$, i.e. $x_j > x_k \forall k \neq j$
3. $a x_i < a x_j$, i.e. $x_i < x_j$.

However 1. and 2. lead to $i = j$, so $x_i = x_j$, another contradiction. So $f(ax) = af(x)$.

Second, we want to prove that $$f(x + y) \leq f(x) + f(y) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$ To do this, we observe that $\forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}, x_i \leq f(x)$. So if $x_i \leq f(x), y_i \leq f(y)$, by adding inequalities we get $$x_i + y_i \leq f(x) + f(y)$$.

Now, the definition of a convex function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $$f(tx + (1 - t)y) \leq tf(x) + (1-t) f(y) \forall t \in [0, 1], x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

But $$\max_i (tx + (1 - t)y)_i \leq \max_i (tx)_i + \max_i ((1-t)y)_i = t \max_i x_i + (1 - t) \max_i y_i$$

So $f(x)$ is convex.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Are you asking us to check if the proof is correct?

Comment: The expression $\sup(x)$ makes no sense, do you mean $\max_k x_k$?

Comment: Mike and Accelerator: Yes, I am asking to check if the proof is correct. I will reword the question. I am sorry for the confusion.
@copper.hat: Yes, but I don't see how sup(x) makes no sense: we can see x as a set, which as any other set indeed has a sup. Of course, since a finite set of reals, it attains its sup, but I don't see how  "sup(x) makes no sense".

Comment: $x$ is not a set, and it is very confusing for anyone familiar with normal use of $\sup$. So if you want solution verification, you may want to consider sticking with convention so that others can read the answer without having to adapt to your peculiar usage.

Comment: @copper.hat My first instinct is to not agree with you, but I trust your judgment. I edited the question accordingly, and removed the external links to proofs that applied to the sup of a set.

Comment: The proof looks fine, you are missing an $a$ after the sentence starting "Then there exists...". Another proof is to note that $\operatorname{epi} f = \cap_i \operatorname{epi} (x \mapsto x_i)$, and since the epigraph of a linear functional is convex (in fact, a half space) and the intersection of convex sets is convex, it follows that the epigraph of $f$ (and hence $f$ itself) is convex.

Comment: Great, thank you for your verification and for the additional insight!

Comment: @copper.hat if you want to make your comment into a one-line answer I can accept it :)

Comment: @kmf I am fairly sure I have answered something similar before ($\sup$ of convex functions) but can't find it atm and don't want to further provoke the MSE gods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@copper.hat confirmed that this proof is correct. Thanks!